# Multiple HttpMessageConverter objects for one endpoint having multiple consumes

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest

Say I have registered 2 `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter<T>` objects:

1. `HttpMessageConverter<Foo>` that will convert the HTTP message to an instance of Foo.class and supports Content-Type "application/foo"
2. `HttpMessageConverter<Bar>` that will convert the HTTP message to an instance of Bar.class and supports Content-Type "application/bar"

I have the below Rest endpoint that consumes both the above:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = POST,
    consumes = {"application/foo", "application/bar"}
public String readFooBar(???){
    ...
}
```

What parameter definition goes in the "???", is it `Foo foo, Bar bar`, `Object canBeFooOrBar` and then downcast in my logic, or something else?

In short, what is the easiest way to deal with 2 separate RequestMapping consumes that generate 2 different objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the nice explanation by [Klaus Groenbaek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41881140/679285), I solved my problem by doing:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = POST,
    consumes = {"application/foo"}
public String readFoo(Foo foo){
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = POST,
    consumes = {"application/bar"}
public String readBar(Bar bar){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the controller method, and any other Java method. If a method has one argument, but you want to pass two different object types(Foo, Bar), then these types must share a common super type (and `Object` does not count, except in very special cases).

Foo and Bar would only share a super type, if the super type has a method (doWork), and the implementation of this method in Foo and Bar contains all the special processing logic (like `Runnable`). If you need to do `instance of` in you Controller method, then you should have two Controller methods, because then Foo and Bar are not related. These a general rules for working with polymeric types.